# Connect 2008 black MacBook to 2013 MBA via Thunderbolt / Firewire?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, migration, migration-assistant, firewire

I am buying a new MacBook Air soon and am getting ready to transfer all of my data via migration assistant. I know this can run via wifi but that is way too slow. My MacBook has a FireWire port, which was how I transferred my data from my older computer that I no longer use to my currently old MacBook that I will be replacing next week. Does anyone sell a male-male Thunderbolt to Firewire cable, and are the reliable? [The Thunderbolt to FireWire adapter that Apple sells](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD464ZM/A/apple-thunderbolt-to-firewire-adapter) is female-male so it won't connect into both ports. It seems to be made more for connecting third-party firewire devices (e.g. cameras, media devices) to newer computers that no longer have firewire ports, only thunderbolt ones. Or in the end should I just give up and connect via USB which will be much slower?

Either way the point is to connect the computers -- whether I use Migration Assistant or not. If I end up just transferring data manually it's the same issue -- I want the fastest connection between the two computers so the process will finish quickly.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a FireWire 800, according to [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4078131?start=0&tstart=0) from an Apple discussion board. [Monoprice](http://www.monoprice.com/products/search.asp?keyword=Firewire+800+9-pin+cable) is a great, online retailer that has cables for a really low price. Take a look at the results that I have linked you. Remember, you need the 9 pin to 9 pin cable if you want to connect two Macbook Pro's together.